# Managedobject becomes nil in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Managedobject is becoming nil when i try to load its attributes in a view controller. My operation flow is as below. All my operations are happening in the main thread(thread1).

1. I save a new entity in MOC1.
2. Then am getting this newly created entity in MOC2 (I have subscribed for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and changes done in MOC1 is merged to MOC2).
3. Then the retrieved Managed Object is set to singleton  class's property.
4. After that I load a view controller.
5. Inside view controller when I try to get attributes of managedobject  from singleton class, I get nil.

Here I create a managedobject from moc2

```
ManagedObjectClass* someClass = (ManagedObjectClass*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ManagedObjectClass" inManagedObjectContext:moc2];

    someClass.orderID = @"123";
    NSError *error = nil;
    moc2 save:&error];
```

// Below is my NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification handler

```
- (void) mocDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *savedContext = [notification object];

    // ignore change notifications for the main MOC
    if ([CoreDataController sharedCoreDataController].moc2 == savedContext)
    {
        return;
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[CoreDataController sharedCoreDataController].moc1 mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    });
}
```

// Now get the created someClass using moc1

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ManagedObjectClass" inManagedObjectContext:moc1];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *matchedPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orderID = 123"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:matchedPredicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *fetchedObjects = [[[moc1 executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]mutableCopy]autorelease];

    // Here am able to see the contents of currentOrder
    [appcontroller sharedAppController].currentOrder = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0]

});
```

// Now load view controller

```
DetailsViewController *aSelectedViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController aNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aSelectedViewController]autorelease];
self.applicationWindow.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

// View controller's implementation

```
@implementation DetailsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if([appcontroller sharedAppController].currentOrder == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"currentOrder became nil");
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Is `currentOrder` a *strong* property of the app delegate?

Comment: Yes @mundi. it is declared as follows `@property (nonatomic, retain) Schleps *currentOrder`